# Adding email addresses to sendgrid with curl command

Tags: javascript, curl, sendgrid

What is the curl command required to add an email to a sendgrid marketing list? I have looked through the documentation and I am having trouble understanding what the actual curl commands would be because the authorization section and the actual api endpoints are split up.  I have tried:

```
curl -X "POST" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients" -H "Authorization: Bearer YOURUSERPASSWORDSTRING" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"list":"Beta List", "email":"bla@bla.com", "name":""}'
```

It still seems to give me issues even if I add a dummy name and YOURUSERPASSWORDSTRING is determined by calling the following in terminal:

```
echo -n "user:password\!" | openssl base64
```

What am I missing? Also, is there a better way to do this using javascript/Meteor.js?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL supports Basic Auth via the `--user` or `-u` flag and will handle the base64 encoding and adding the auth header.

Try

`curl -X "POST" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients" -u username:password -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"list":"Beta List", "email":"bla@bla.com", "name":""}'`

And for a bit more info, here's an example from the [SendGrid Web API auth docs](https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/Web_API_v3/index.html#-Authentication).

Comment: Thanks! I found out that this also worked after I created an API key under settings: curl -X "POST" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/contactdb/recipients" -H "Authorization: Bearer APICODE" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '[{"email":"bla42@bla.com"}]'

Comment: Nice, that's the preferred method. API keys are definitely cleaner

Comment: @bwest can you look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805193/how-to-add-contact-in-list-using-php-api

Comment: @Coherent can you post your answer i am not able add contact in list see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37805193/how-to-add-contact-in-list-using-send-grid-php-api